# Cordova/Phonegap hybrid android app on blackberry: can't access asset file

Tags: android, blackberry, cordova

I've created a hybrid HTML5 Android app based on Cordova/Phonegap, that i want to deploy on Blackberry using the Android app converter. 
My startup html file is located in the assets folder of my Android app. After deploying my app on Blackberry 10 simulator and starting it, i'm getting an application error,
saying that the protocol isn't supported. 
I changed my url to "asset:///www/index.html" already.

What can i do to fix that?

Thanks, Stephan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I located my problem and solved it:

I was using an older version of Phonegap in conjunction with the now deprecated plugin.xml. I switched to config.xml, using the access origin and content source tag, and I changed my startup url to file:///android_asset/www/index.html, which now works both with Android and Blackberry.

Comment: what version of Phonegap/Cordova did you have to use?